# Visual Basic GUI Input Validation

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

I took an entry level computer programming class this past term and I'm having problems with my final project.  I have to design a program in visual basic GUI that asks the player to accurately guess a number between 1-100 within a limited number of guesses.

My first form asks the user to set the number of guesses allowed.  It has one textbox and an "enter" button, among other buttons that I've gotten to work.

I'm trying to get code to work that will validate the input on the guesses allowed.  Specifically, I want a message box to pop up if the player enters letters or special characters instead of numbers, or enters a number less than zero, or greater than twenty.  Here's what I have:

```
Public Class Noofguesses
    Shared maxguesscnt As Integer
    Private Sub Numberofguesses_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Numberofguesses.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Quit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Quit.Click
        End
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Form3.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Val(Numberofguesses) > 20 Then MsgBox("Number of Guesses Cannot Exceed 20")
        If Val(Numberofguesses) < 0 Then MsgBox("Number of Guesses  Must Be Greater Than 0")
        If Not IsNumeric(Numberofguesses) Then MsgBox("Entry Cannot be Letters or Characters")
        Me.Close()
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

What am I doing wrong?  Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I cannot stress this enough.  NEVER use `End` to exit an application.  If you want to exit a WinForms app then either call `Application.Exit` or call `Close` on the main form.

Answer (score 1):

I would generally suggest using a `NumericUpDown` rather than a `TextBox`, in which case no validation is required.  As this is an assignment though, I'm guessing that validating a `TextBox` is a requirement.  In that case, you should use `Integer.TryParse` to validate a `String`, i.e. the `Text` of the `TextBox` and convert it if it is valid.  You can then test the converted value to make sure that it isn't less than zero, etc.  I'm not going to write the code for you, given that this is homework, but that should be enough for you to do it yourself or, if you feel you must, find examples online.